# CakePHP error: Call to undefined method FlashComponent::error()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am now practising the blog tutorial of CakePHP, and I follow every single step or instruction of it. Still, I'm not able to add posts because this error pops up:

```
Error: Call to undefined method FlashComponent::error() 
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sembreak\app\Controller\PostsController.php   
Line: 29
```

What is the reason for this error and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post your code for line 29 of `PostsController` and state the version of CakePHP you are using.

Comment: $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
version 2.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using `$this->Session->setFlash()` not `$this->Flash->error()` for versions of CakePHP lower than 2.7.0:-

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
```

The clue is in the error message you were getting "Call to undefined method".